# Possible to launch command line air app?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

Is it possible to create a command line Abode Air app? I know thats not the intended use of the framework, but I have a lot of utility code written in as3, and I have a need to programatically run some utility functions from another app (not flash).

I know I can pass command line parameters to the Air app, but I would like to avoid having a window pop up while the calculations are being made.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to set the visibility of the window to false in the descriptor xml and still being able to communicate with the AIR app if you compile it to a native application using AIR 2 and NativeProcess.

Look like it should work.

J